# Trig function when element finished to resize thorugh resizable

Tags: jquery, masonry

I want to trigger masonry when I finish to resize element, here is my example http://jsfiddle.net/oanj5fo4/4/ but when I resize, my browser can't handle (freez) **msnry.layout()**, how can I trig **msnry.layout()** when resize of element is finished?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.item').resizable();
        var container = document.querySelector('.masonry');
        var msnry = new Masonry(container, {
            columnWidth: 60
        });
    $(function () {
            var prevHeight = $('.item').height();
            var prevWidth = $('.item').width();
            $('.item').attrchange({
                callback: function (e) {
                    var curHeight = $(this).height();
                    var curWidth = $(this).width();
                    if (prevHeight !== curHeight || prevWidth !== curWidth) {
                        console.log('height changed from ' + prevHeight + ' to ' + curHeight);
                        prevHeight = curHeight;
                        prevWidth = curWidth;
                        // msnry.layout();
                    }
                }
            }).resizable();
        });
    });
```

I'm using external libs:

1. masonry
2. attrchange

My task is to make resizable containers with auto arrange/responsive layout in page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked in the source of resizable and found callback function **stop** so I added timeout to help Masonry to detect new layout of container after resize:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.item').resizable();
    var container = document.querySelector('.masonry');
    var msnry = new Masonry(container, {
        columnWidth: 60
    });

    $(function () {
        $('.item').resizable({
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    msnry.layout();
                }, 300);
            }
        });
    });
});
```